# Oracle Repositry error

Tags: java, oracle, repository, oracleforms

I have been trying to install oracle 12c and oracle forms and reports.

So first,I  already installed jdk 8 and infrastructure setup then installed forms and deployment setup then when i try to create to repository this shows error

I follow this link also check image which i taken from this link

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/install-fnr/install.htm#CIHGBBEH

[image]

Error at the time of installation

[image]

ERROR

> **Unable to connect to the DB. Check if DB connection details entered are correct. Unable to connect to the database using the provided
>   details. Enter a valid hostname and port or check if the listener is
>   up and running.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database is up and running and that you're providing the correct DB connection info to the RCU (host name the database is running on, its listener port and service name).
[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/articles-12c) you can find some useful guides on how to install the database and configure Forms and Reports.